# iOS: Correct way to show internet / loading spinner?

Tags: objective-c, concurrency

I'm trying to have a loading spinner showing (currently using [DejalActivityView](https://github.com/Dejal/DejalActivityView) *(DAV)*) for an iOS app whenever internet activity takes place.

I'm wondering if I've got the approach / pattern right:

1. I have a base View Controller that all my ViewControllers inherits from,
2. I set up a notification observer on the Base VC

   ```
   self.observerStartSpinner = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kNotification_key_startspinner object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
               [DejalActivityView activityViewForView:self.view withLabel:@"Loading..."];
               [DejalActivityView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:nil];
       }
   ```
3. Surrounding the code blocks where I have the asynchronous call for internet activity:

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotification_key_startspinner object:nil userInfo:nil];

   // Do all the network setup necessary for asynchronous call

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotification_key_stopspinner object:nil];
   ```

**Issues**

The above doesn't work. But if I sprinkle (in lots of place) where the UIView calls the function for the interactivity (in (3) above), this does work.  It's really strange.  But I have a feeling it has to do with the timing of when the UIView actually loads (in (2))

**Questions**

- What is the approach you use to show a loading spinner while making asynch network calls?
- Does your approach for every single ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I use the MBProgressHUD... https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

It works really well...

Similarly to you. I start the Spinner and then when I receive a NSNotification that my async process if finished, I stop and close the HUD.